# Who do you think is the richest man?

Tags: questions, interrogatives, do-support

In some old Toefl test, there is a question like this:

> ______in this town?
>
> I think Mr. Kim is the richest man.
>
> A. Who do you think is the richest man
>
> B. Who you think is the richest man

I would choose B since it sounds better. But what's wrong with A (or B)?

Comment: A, because it is a question.

Comment: Thanks, now I have no idea why I think B is correct before...

Comment: Maybe you heard it in spoken speach ..

Comment: Can I discuss about the comment that CYC made? I am confused what is the right form of that sentence.NO-1 Or NO-2.
NO-1 "Now I have no idea why had I thought B was correct before?".
NO-2 "Now I have no idea why did I thought B was correct before?".

I think sentence NO-1 is correct.Here Now and Before these two words were used.That shows the action that he thought B was correct happened earlier than the action he have no idea.For that reason had was used in place of did..

But I am not sure that i am right..Help anyone??

Comment: I think that it is not question so it shall be: "Now I have no idea why I had thought before B was correct."

Comment: @TzD you should ask that as a proper question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ______in this town?
>
> I think Mr. Kim is the richest man.
>
> A. Who do you think is the richest man.
>
> B. Who you think is the richest man.

In a question, [the subject and the verb must be inverted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93auxiliary_inversion#In_questions), **which means the verb must come *before* the subject**. Making it clearer, I will use this statement :

> I think *he* is the richest man.

We are making question about *him*, so *Who* is *he*? I dont know. Now, I'll **1. take out the word *him* and add in the question word *who* in the beginning of the sentence**. I will also **2. change the word *I* to *you***

> *Who* *you* think  is the richest man.

Now, I will **3. put the verb in front of the noun**.The clause that should be inverted is *"you think"*. Since the verb *think* is a [normal verb](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/types.html) which can't be inverted, the correct way to invert this sentence is adding the [helping verb](http://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verbs-what_classification-helping.htm#preH1) *do* right before *"you think"*.

> Who *do* you think is the richest man.

The correct answer is therefore, (A).

Comment: I don't think it's helpful to say that (B) is also correct. It isn't, because it's not a question. English questions **must** have inverted verbs (except maybe in unusual or very informal grammar).

Comment: OK, I understand. That's misleading. I'm actually trying to say that it's quite OK to use (B) in daily life talking with friends and things.

Comment: Perhaps it's a dialect thing; maybe in some places it would be normal in casual English. All I can say for sure is that in my dialect (Australian English), no native speaker would ask the question as (B).

Comment: My friend in Canada says that they don't care about the inverted subject-verb thing. As long as everyone understands, it's OK. (I'm Thai and if I say something wrong in English, they don't know that it's wrong. =b)

Answer (score -1):

As Leos says, questions are **better formed** with that format.

> Who do you think is the richest man -preferred 
>   Who you think is the richest man - less preferred *(informal?)* 
>  Who, you think, is the richest man_- okay

Note that both the structures are *okay* though.

> I've read and heard both - *What you want? **and** What do you want?*

Maybe, without *do* the question is common in (informal?) speech.

A famous gag

[image]

Comment: It's not really okay without the auxiliary.

Comment: @snailplane But as I said I've heard it in  informal speech.

Comment: By the way, that gag contains a noun phrase, not a question.

Comment: @snailplane I believe both ***"Who do you think is the richest man?"*** as well as ***"Who you think is the richest man?"*** are correct. I think there is no confusion of the first one being right. Now consider the second one - ***"Who, you think, is the richest man?". This a question ***"Who is the richest man?"***

Comment: @Man_From_India this is very good